# Non-abstract method showing as abstract in PHP fatal error message

Tags: php, expressionengine

I am getting this PHP fatal error message: "Fatal error: Class PT_Fieldtype contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (EE_Fieldtype::display_field) in /.../pt_fieldtype.php on line 148"

However, when I open the file and do a search, the word "abstract" is nowhere to be found at all. Thanks for the help!

Edit: Here's the code in question. My bad for not showing it before.

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


if (! defined('PT_FIELD_PACK_VER'))
{
    // get the version from config.php
    require PATH_THIRD.'pt_field_pack/config.php';
    define('PT_FIELD_PACK_VER', $config['version']);
}


/**
 * P&T Fieldtype Base Class
 *
 * @package   P&T Field Pack
 * @author    Brandon Kelly <brandon@pixelandtonic.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 Pixel & Tonic, LLC
 */
class PT_Fieldtype extends EE_Fieldtype {

    /**
     * PT_Fieldtype Constructor
     */
    function PT_Fieldtype()
    {
        parent::EE_Fieldtype();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Options Setting
     */
    function options_setting($options=array(), $indent = '')
    {
        $r = '';

        foreach($options as $name => $label)
        {
            if ($r !== '') $r .= "\n";

            // is this just a blank option?
            if (! $name && ! $label) $name = $label = ' ';

            $r .= $indent . htmlentities($name);

            // is this an optgroup?
            if (is_array($label)) $r .= "\n".$this->options_setting($label, $indent.'    ');
            else if ($name != $label) $r .= ' : '.$label;
        }

        return $r;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Save Options Setting
     */
    function save_options_setting($options = '', $total_levels = 1)
    {
        // prepare options
        $options = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $options);
        foreach($options as &$option)
        {
            $option_parts = preg_split('/\s:\s/', $option, 2);
            $option = array();
            $option['indent'] = preg_match('/^\s+/', $option_parts[0], $matches) ? strlen(str_replace("\t", '    ', $matches[0])) : 0;
            $option['name']   = trim($option_parts[0]);
            $option['value']  = isset($option_parts[1]) ? trim($option_parts[1]) : $option['name'];
        }

        return $this->_structure_options($options, $total_levels);
    }

    /**
     * Structure Options
     */
    private function _structure_options(&$options, $total_levels, $level = 1, $indent = -1)
    {
        $r = array();

        while ($options)
        {
            if ($indent == -1 || $options[0]['indent'] > $indent)
            {
                $option = array_shift($options);
                $children = (! $total_levels OR $level < $total_levels)
                              ?  $this->_structure_options($options, $total_levels, $level+1, $option['indent']+1)
                              :  FALSE;
                $r[(string)$option['name']] = $children ? $children : (string)$option['value'];
            }
            else if ($options[0]['indent'] <= $indent)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return $r;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Prep Iterators
     */
    function prep_iterators(&$tagdata)
    {
        // find {switch} tags
        $this->_switches = array();
        $tagdata = preg_replace_callback('/'.LD.'switch\s*=\s*([\'\"])([^\1]+)\1'.RD.'/sU', array(&$this, '_get_switch_options'), $tagdata);

        $this->_count_tag = 'count';
        $this->_iterator_count = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get Switch Options
     */
    function _get_switch_options($match)
    {
        global $FNS;

        $marker = LD.'SWITCH['.$FNS->random('alpha', 8).']SWITCH'.RD;
        $this->_switches[] = array('marker' => $marker, 'options' => explode('|', $match[2]));
        return $marker;
    }

    /**
     * Parse Iterators
     */
    function parse_iterators(&$tagdata)
    {
        // {switch} tags
        foreach($this->_switches as $i => $switch)
        {
            $option = $this->_iterator_count % count($switch['options']);
            $tagdata = str_replace($switch['marker'], $switch['options'][$option], $tagdata);
        }

        // update the count
        $this->_iterator_count++;

        // {count} tags
        $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single($this->_count_tag, $this->_iterator_count, $tagdata);
    }

}


// ====================================================================


/**
 * P&T Multi Fieldtype Base Class
 * 
 * @package   P&T Field Pack
 * @author    Brandon Kelly <brandon@pixelandtonic.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 Pixel & Tonic, LLC
 */
class PT_Multi_Fieldtype extends PT_Fieldtype {

    var $default_field_settings = array(
        'options' => array(
            'Option 1' => 'Option 1',
            'Option 2' => 'Option 2',
            'Option 3' => 'Option 3'
        )
    );

    var $default_cell_settings = array(
        'options' => array(
            'Opt 1' => 'Opt 1',
            'Opt 2' => 'Opt 2'
        )
    );

    var $default_tag_params = array(
        'sort'      => '',
        'backspace' => '0'
    );

    var $total_option_levels = 1;

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Display Field Settings
     */
    function display_settings($data)
    {
        // load the language file
        $this->EE->lang->loadfile($this->class);

        $options = isset($data['options']) ? $data['options'] : array();
        $input_name = $this->class.'_options';

        $this->EE->table->add_row(
            lang($this->class.'_options', $input_name) . '<br />'
            . lang('field_list_instructions') . '<br /><br />'
            . lang('option_setting_examples'),

            '<textarea id="'.$input_name.'" name="'.$input_name.'" rows="6">'.$this->options_setting($options).'</textarea>'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Display Cell Settings
     */
    function display_cell_settings($data)
    {
        // load the language file
        $this->EE->lang->loadfile($this->class);

        $options = isset($data['options']) ? $data['options'] : array();

        return array(
            array(
                lang($this->class.'_options'),
                '<textarea class="matrix-textarea" name="options" rows="4">'.$this->options_setting($options).'</textarea>'
            )
        );
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Save Field Settings
     */
    function save_settings($data)
    {
        $post = $this->EE->input->post($this->class.'_options');

        // replace quotes
        $post = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $post);

        return array(
            'options' => $this->save_options_setting($post, $this->total_option_levels)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Save Cell Settings
     */
    function save_cell_settings($settings)
    {
        // replace quotes
        $settings['options'] = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $settings['options']);

        $settings['options'] = $this->save_options_setting($settings['options'], $this->total_option_levels);
        return $settings;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Prep Field Data
     *
     * Ensures $field_data is an array.
     */
    function prep_field_data(&$data)
    {
        if (! is_array($data))
        {
            $data = array_filter(preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $data));
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Display Field
     */
    function display_field($data)
    {
        if (is_string($data)) $data = html_entity_decode($data);

        return $this->_display_field($data, $this->field_name);
    }

    /**
     * Display Cell
     */
    function display_cell($data)
    {
        return $this->_display_field($data, $this->cell_name);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Save
     */
    function save($data)
    {
        // replace quotes
        return str_replace('"', '&quot;', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Save Cell
     */
    function save_cell($data)
    {
        // replace quotes
        return $this->save($data);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Find Options
     */
    private function _find_option($needle, $haystack)
    {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $value)
        {
            $r = $value;
            if ($needle == $key OR (is_array($value) AND (($r = $this->_find_option($needle, $value)) !== FALSE)))
            {
                return $r;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Replace Tag
     */
    function replace_tag($data, $params = array(), $tagdata = FALSE)
    {
        if (! isset($this->settings['options']) || ! $this->settings['options'])
        {
            return $data;
        }

        if (! $tagdata)
        {
            return $this->replace_ul($data, $params);
        }

        $this->prep_field_data($data);
        $r = '';

        if ($this->settings['options'] && $data)
        {
            // optional sorting
            if (isset($params['sort']) && $params['sort'])
            {
                $sort = strtolower($params['sort']);

                if ($sort == 'asc')
                {
                    sort($data);
                }
                else if ($sort == 'desc')
                {
                    rsort($data);
                }
            }

            // offset and limit
            if (isset($params['offset']) || isset($params['limit']))
            {
                $offset = isset($params['offset']) ? $params['offset'] : 0;
                $limit = isset($params['limit']) ? $params['limit'] : count($data);
                $data = array_splice($data, $offset, $limit);
            }

            // prepare for {switch} and {count} tags
            $this->prep_iterators($tagdata);

            foreach($data as $option_name)
            {
                if (($option = $this->_find_option($option_name, $this->settings['options'])) !== FALSE)
                {
                    // copy $tagdata
                    $option_tagdata = $tagdata;

                    // simple var swaps
                    $option_tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single('option', $option, $option_tagdata);
                    $option_tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single('option_name', $option_name, $option_tagdata);

                    // parse {switch} and {count} tags
                    $this->parse_iterators($option_tagdata);

                    $r .= $option_tagdata;
                }
            }

            if (isset($params['backspace']) && $params['backspace'])
            {
                $r = substr($r, 0, -$params['backspace']);
            }
        }

        return $r;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Unordered List
     */
    function replace_ul($data, $params = array())
    {
        return "<ul>\n"
             .   $this->replace_tag($data, $params, "  <li>{option}</li>\n")
             . '</ul>';
    }

    /**
     * Ordered List
     */
    function replace_ol($data, $params = array())
    {
        return "<ol>\n"
             .   $this->replace_tag($data, $params, "  <li>{option}</li>\n")
             . '</ol>';
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * All Options
     */
    function replace_all_options($data, $params = array(), $tagdata = FALSE, $options = FALSE, $iterator_count = 0)
    {
        if (! $tagdata)
        {
            return "<ul>\n"
                 .   $this->replace_all_options($data, $params, "  <li>{option}</li>\n")
                 . "</ul>";
        }

        PT_Multi_Fieldtype::prep_field_data($data);

        $r = '';

        if ($options === FALSE)
        {
            $options = $this->settings['options'];
        }

        if ($options)
        {
            // optional sorting
            if (isset($params['sort']) && $params['sort'])
            {
                $sort = strtolower($params['sort']);

                if ($sort == 'asc')
                {
                    asort($options);
                }
                else if ($sort == 'desc')
                {
                    arsort($options);
                }
            }

            // prepare for {switch} and {count} tags
            $this->prep_iterators($tagdata);
            $this->_iterator_count += $iterator_count;

            foreach($options as $option_name => $option)
            {
                if (is_array($option))
                {
                    $sub_params = array_merge($params, array('backspace' => '0'));
                    $r .= $this->replace_all_options($data, $sub_params, $tagdata, $option, $this->_iterator_count);
                }
                else
                {
                    // copy $tagdata
                    $option_tagdata = $tagdata;

                    // simple var swaps
                    $option_tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single('option', $option, $option_tagdata);
                    $option_tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single('option_name', $option_name, $option_tagdata);
                    $option_tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single('selected', (in_array($option_name, $data) ? 1 : 0), $option_tagdata);

                    // parse {switch} and {count} tags
                    $this->parse_iterators($option_tagdata);

                    $r .= $option_tagdata;
                }
            }

            if (isset($params['backspace']) && $params['backspace'])
            {
                $r = substr($r, 0, -$params['backspace']);
            }
        }

        return $r;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Is Selected?
     */
    function replace_selected($data, $params = array())
    {
        $this->prep_field_data($data);

        return (isset($params['option']) AND in_array($params['option'], $data)) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * Total Selections
     */
    function replace_total_selections($data, $params = array())
    {
        $this->prep_field_data($data);

        return $field_data ? (string) count($data) : '0';
    }

}
```

Comment: "Abstract" is also a class with at least one prototype only (function without body). If a function body is missing, a class cannot be instantiated. Show some code...

Comment: How do you want us to help if you don't post your code? Are we meant to _guess_ what is in line 148?

Comment: If you are using Field Pack from Field and Tonic, they fixed it few weeks ago in 2.1.1 version ([changelog](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/changelog.html#field-pack-2-1-1)).

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel I am actually using Field Pack and I do see they release an updated version, but how can I update what I have now? I cannot access the fieldtype screen in the EE control panel because when I do, it crashes and I get this PHP fatal error message.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know ExpressionEngine. Maybe you can try by replacing PHP files of the extension. See [download page](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack).

Comment: This question was [recently asked on EE Stack Exchange here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13477/2-7-update-error-with-pt-fieldtype). The answers there, in conjunction with the update instructions from P&T will tell you what need to know (how to suppress the error and update). The [P&T Field Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pt-field-pack) has been superseded by [Field Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack).

Answer (score 2):

The answer of your question is on line 148 of this file...

Maybe you are using a class with abstract methods without inheriting them that is rejected, make sure you implement all of them and after show us some code. ;-)